# Rails 4 Javascript Image Path

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to load an image in the javascript on a rails app,

The javascript works in the application, just the tab image does not load and believe its probably a image path issue, The image is in the images folder.

```
$(function(){
         $('.divslide').SlideOut({
             Handle: '.handle',  
             pathToTabImage: 'images/menu.png', 
             ...
```

I have tried changing the paths with no luck, Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: It would be very nice of you to accept the best answer, cause it's quite messy to look through all of them.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly make sure that you have `.erb` extanstion on your `.js` file, like

```
main.js -> main.js.erb
```

And now you can use the [asset_path()](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path) helper:

```
$(function(){
     $('.divslide').SlideOut({
        Handle: '.handle',  
        pathToTabImage: '<%= asset_path("images/menu.png") %>', 
        ...
```

Where the image must be in `app/assets/images` folder.

Answer (score 0):

The correct path should be `/assets/menu.png`

Comment: Thank you, Same thing popped into my head after asking and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Changed path and got it working

```
$(function(){
     $('.divslide').SlideOut({
         Handle: '.handle',  
         pathToTabImage: 'images/menu.png', 
         ...
```

to

```
$(function(){
     $('.divslide').SlideOut({
         Handle: '.handle',  
         pathToTabImage: 'assets/menu.png', 
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if it is in the images folder than it should be

```
pathToTabImage: 'assets/images/menu.png',
```